# Django templates. I get in my mail parameters, how can I send them to another html with include?

Tags: html, django, django-templates, include, email-templates

This is my welcome container:

```
<tr>
<td align="center">
    <!-- Start internal container -->
    <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
        <tr>
            <td height="30" style="line-height:30px; font-size:30px;">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="left" style="font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif; font-size:20px; line-height:26px;">
                <p style="font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif; margin: 0; padding: 15px 60px 15px 60px; font-weight: bold; color: #333333;">
                    {{ title }}
                </p>
                <p style="font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif; font-size:16px; margin: 0; padding: 0px 60px 0px 60px; color: #333333;">
                    {{ subtitle }}
                </p>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <!-- End internal container -->
</td>
```

I tried this:

```
  {% "Hi {{first_name}}" as  titleStr%}
  {% with title=titleStr subtitle="Please confirm your email address by clicking this button." %}
      {% include "emails/_parts/welcome_container.html" %}
  {% endwith %}
```

But I get this issue:

```
Invalid block tag on line 29: '"Hi', expected 'endblock'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?
```

What am I doing wrong? Line 29 is the one with title=titleStr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have added `{% "Hi" %}` in template where django considers 'Hi' as template tag but it does not exists in django and that's why its throwing an error. You probably want add Hello in front of title variable and pass it to the another template. You can do this via `add` template tag.

```
{% with "Hello "|add:first_name as titleStr %}
     {% include 'emails/_parts/welcome_container.html' with title=titleStr subtitle="Please confirm your email address by clicking this button." %}    
{% endwith %}
```

Answer (score 0):

you write `{% "Hi`, and django template know this is start of block tag. If you want show text only, change it to `"Hi {{first_name}}"`

if you want pass variable with include, try this:

`{% include "emails/_parts/welcome_container.html" with title={{first_name}} %}`

document for include https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/templates/builtins/#include

Comment: This code gives me this:
`TemplateSyntaxError at /mail/account/confirm
Could not parse the remainder: '{{first_name}}' from '{{first_name}}'`

Comment: i cant see anything in this html question contain `/mail/account/confirm`. Its maybe happen from another code. Try find your code and remove it temporary for test

Comment: It's from that line. I did it with the logic Aniket Pawar provided me and that worked